# Why does flow show an error in this case?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

my code:

```
/* @flow */

type Manager = {id: number, name: string};
type Target = {
  id: number,
  title: string,
};
type Form = {
  manager: ?Manager,
  target: ?Target,
}

const form: Form = {
  manager: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
    },
  target: {
    id: 2,
    title: 'test'
  }
};

if (form.manager && form.target) {
  const managerId = +form.manager.id;
  const currentLimits = ([/* array from state*/].find(
    (limit) => limit.managersId === managerId,
  ) || {})
    .data || {};
  const { id: triggerId } = form.target; // <-- error here: "property `id` is missing in null or undefined [1]"
...
}
```

[flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAhgHbEDmeATmALxgDeAlgCYBcYpArgLYBGNADRdivPJwDOGas1IUAvgG5MuAgBVi1KhnpNUYMG048Bwg2AzMMMCWGmz5Q1MtX4wAMTjVeexhd4yShpOAH4ScipqZ0MMLR0wzW08DGcFdABjOFJpMChvXk4vHz8AoKjOf0NDYzAARhjq8nFOAHIMPGlWi0MFRrjkjEqeow4wACZG2OtbNo6ui3TXVGYoMAAKfJ8AOkDImjAAMkO8gu2BnQBKfWrqrJzdPeDqAElWPQBqLd5d8ppttgqW6Ge65DLcajUPCkDAAGWYvGskj06wA2qAwFpqMQsHlqHBfNJiB0UABdbZQOSsdYjW7rGAI6zXOgAPjADMRGF++2okje9DoDCeUTeU2q1wAPhKmApLrTqttWMTiGApTKgcDQbpGKNODJmBQRe8FHpvud4ikNb0gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a presence of callback in `array.find` which invalidates type refinement done before by the `if (form.manager && form.target)` statement.

More info on refinement invalidations [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations)

---

Quick fix for this would be extracting `target` to its own variable before refinement:

```
const { manager, target } = form;

if (manager && target) {
  const managerId = +manager.id;
  const currentLimits = ([/* array from state*/].find(
    (limit) => limit.managersId === managerId,
  ) || {}).data || {};
  const { id: triggerId } = target;
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAhgHbEDmeATmALxgDeAlgCYBcYpArgLYBGNADRdivPJwDOGas1IUAvgG5MuAgBVi1KhnpNUYMG048Bwg2AzMMMCWGmz5Q1MtX4wAMTjVeexhd4yShpOAH4ScipqZ0MMLR0wzW08DGcFdABjOFJpMChvXk4vHz8AoKjOf0NDYzAARhjq8nFOAHIMPGlWi0MFRrjkjEqeow4wACZG2OtbNo6ui3TXVCyc3UYwQMjhS3iUsAU9fJ8VVGYoMAAKLeDaADI73cGASn1DVdybqIBJVj0Aai+NAAdGwVO9srkMtxqNQ8KQMAAZZi8aySPSXADaoDAWmoxCweWocF80mIHRQAF1gVA5KxLiNLjAUdZXnQAHxgZmojDAoHUSS-eh0Bj836NV4AH0lTAUz2BrHJxDA0tl4LAH3Wo04MmYFB+f0ODAGOhUCiAA)

Or just moving destructuring up before the `find` callback:

```
if (form.manager && form.target) {
  const managerId = +form.manager.id;
  const { id: triggerId } = form.target;
  const currentLimits = ([/* array from state*/].find(
    (limit) => limit.managersId === managerId,
  ) || {})
    .data || {};
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAhgHbEDmeATmALxgDeAlgCYBcYpArgLYBGNADRdivPJwDOGas1IUAvgG5MuAgBVi1KhnpNUYMG048Bwg2AzMMMCWGmz5Q1MtX4wAMTjVeexhd4yShpOAH4ScipqZ0MMLR0wzW08DGcFdABjOFJpMChvXk4vHz8AoKjOf0NDYzAARhjq8nFOAHIMPGlWi0MFRrjkjEqeow4wACZG2OtbNo6ui3TXVGYoMAAKfJ8AOkDImjAAMkO8gu2BnQBKfUMsnN094OoASVY9AGot3l3ymm22FS3bK5RijTgyZgUKKvMAKPRfc7xFKAsB3XIZbjUah4UgYAAyzF41kkenWAG1QGAtNRiFg8tQ4L5pMQOigALrbKByVjrEbrGCE6zXOgAPjAAqJGB++2okhhdAVYEe0NYjWuAB91UwFJcRttWCziGBNdqVAogA)

Answer (score 0):

Because your type for `form.target` is `target: ?Target` which means "`Target` or `null/undefined`".

You would need to check for null beforehand or remove the `?` (but only if you are sure that it can't be null).

**Example:**

```
if (form.manager && form.target) {
  const managerId = +form.manager.id;
  const currentLimits = ([/* array from state*/].find(
    (limit) => limit.managersId === managerId,
  ) || {})
    .data || {};

  if(form.target != null) { // <-- Check for null
    const { id: triggerId } = form.target;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: but I checked it in the condition above `if (form.manager && form.target) {`

Comment: Yeah, but flow doesn't seem to get that. I don't know why - never worked with flow. Just telling you what happened and how to fix it. Maybe someone else knows why, but for now here you have a fix. @Kekcuuuk

Comment: The reason is refinement invalidation happening due to callback in `([/* array from state*/].find(...` Flow assumes that the value can be changed there

Answer (score 0):

The field `target` on type `Form` is optional, and Flow is not clever enough to see that the `if (form.manager && form.target)` check protects against `form.target` being `null` or `undefined`.

If you wrap your `form.target` access in an if clause that *only* checks `form.target` is truthy, it will work.

```
let triggerId = null;
if (form.target) {
  ({ id: triggerId } = form.target);
}
```

[See this example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAhgHbEDmeATmALxgDeAlgCYBcYpArgLYBGNADRdivPJwDOGas1IUAvgG5MuAgBVi1KhnpNUYMG048Bwg2AzMMMCWGmz5Q1MtX4wAMTjVeexhd4yShpOAH4ScipqZ0MMLR0wzW08DGcFdABjOFJpMChvXk4vHz8AoKjOf0NDYzAARhjq8nFOAHIMPGlWi0MFRrjkjEqeow4wACZG2OtbNo6ui3TXVGYoMAAKfJ8AOkDImjAAMkO8gu2BnQBKfWrqrJzdPeDqAElWPQBqLd5d8ppttgqW6Ge65DLcajUPCkDAAGWYvGskj06wA2qAwFpqMQsHlqHBfNJiB0UABdbZQOSsdYjW7rGAI6zXOgAPjADMRGF++2okje9DoDCeUTeU2q1wAPhKmApLrTqttWMTiGApTKgcDbLoZMwKCL3gweDAYBrbqsNt9zvEUtcqsDDOtGKNODq9TR+Qo9JaLjbTdV0rcFEA).